# Plot trendine using geom_density combined with geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to first plot a histogram and then I am adding geom_density() to get a trend line, but instead of trend line i am getting a flat line parallel to x axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data= MyData, aes(x= MyData$Top.10..HS)) +  
     geom_histogram(breaks=seq(40,100, by = 10),col="red", fill="blue", 
     alpha =0.2) + geom_density()
```

[image]

Comment: Your problem is likely because your histogram is showing counts, where your `geom_density` is not. You can add `aes(y = ..density..)` to your `geom_histogram` call and you will see both on the same scale.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `aes(y = ..count..)` in `geom_density()` to get them on the same scale (otherwise area under the density curve is ~1 and in won't match histogram scale).

```
# Generate data
MyData <- data.frame(X = rnorm(100, 70, 10))
# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(MyData, aes(X)) +  
    geom_histogram(breaks = seq(40, 100, 10),
                   col = "red", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) + 
    geom_density(aes(y = ..count..))
```

[image]